# Importing a python standard library with the same name as the current module

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to build a Python project, and the name of the current module (lets call it email) is the same name as a module in the standard library. I need to import from the standard library, but I am getting an error with trying to import from the library.

Example:

```
Project/
    email.py

# email.py script
import email

# do something with the standard email library.
```

Is there any way I can still keep the name of my module email.py, or is the best option changing it? I have done some research, and they seem to relate more to having a case like this:

```
Project/
    main.py # Current module
    email.py
```

Comment: It's generally bad practice to name your own module the same as something in the Standard Library. (You can add subcomponents that share names e.g. `foolib.email.whatever`, but top-level components should never conflict.)

Comment: I have to ask, why did you name the file the same as a module you are importing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it is bad practice to create a module that shadows another module. However, that doesn't prevent you from proceeding.

Import `__future__ import absolute_import` as your first import in your `main` file.

This forces imports to use absolute paths instead of relative. Now, `import email` imports that standard library. You can import your local version by `from . import email`

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to change your own module's name. Conflicting names are always terrible in Python!

One time I crashed IDLE and my python just because I had a file called `code.py`