# AttributeError: module 'ternary' has no attribute 'figure'

Tags: python

I'm trying out the supplied examples for ternary plots, but I'm getting the error

> AttributeError: module 'ternary' has no attribute 'figure'

As far as I can tell based on some searching this seems to be due to the way the package is imported. Don't see how I can do this differently though. (did try to reinstall the package)
To be clear: the file is not called ternary.py

```
import ternary
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## Boundary and Gridlines
scale = 30
figure, tax = ternary.figure(scale=scale)
figure.set_size_inches(10, 10)
figure.set_dpi(600)

# Draw Boundary and Gridlines
tax.boundary(linewidth=2.0)
tax.gridlines(color="black", multiple=6)
tax.gridlines(color="blue", multiple=2, linewidth=0.5)

# Set Axis labels and Title
fontsize = 20
tax.set_title("Simplex Boundary and Gridlines", fontsize=fontsize)
tax.left_axis_label("Left label $\\alpha^2$", fontsize=fontsize)
tax.right_axis_label("Right label $\\beta^2$", fontsize=fontsize)
tax.bottom_axis_label("Bottom label $\\Gamma - \\Omega$", fontsize=fontsize)

# Set ticks
tax.ticks(axis='lbr', linewidth=1)

# Remove default Matplotlib Axes
tax.clear_matplotlib_ticks()

ternary.plt.show()
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: forgot to edit the code back to initial state. I tried to import ternary as ter as per a suggestion I found elsewhere to see if that would work. No luck so reverted back to the original code example.

Comment: Have you called your script `ternary.py`? If so, rename it

Comment: @roganjosh yes I did, renaming makes sense indeed. Unfortunately doesn't solve the issue though

Comment: How are you calling this script? Do you import it once and call the block again and again in an interactive session? Is it in a jupyter notebook? Or do you just run it with `python script.py` whenever you want to run it? With the first two, your import will be cached and since it was shadowed by the filename it will not work without restarting the session.

Comment: @Chrisvdberge renaming is not in terms of "making sense". Having your script with the same name as the library will cause it to shadow the library and cause exactly the issue you describe. I'm pretty confident that will have been the issue. If you are using iPython, restart the kernel, it's possible that your own script has been cached and continues to shadow the actual library.

Comment: re-install the package and try..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing a python standard library with the same name as the current module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24835662/importing-a-python-standard-library-with-the-same-name-as-the-current-module)

Comment: For reference I'm getting the same error and I didn't name my file ternary. Running in PyCharm or Jupiter, I get the same issue.

Comment: @AndrewMcDowell hmm ok, I'll have a go

Comment: @Graipher I'm using Pycharm to run the script (using virtual environment). Tried renaming the file, restarting Pycharm, re-installing the package. still same error.
this is probably a major n00b-question, but the package seems to be named python-ternary and not just ternary. does this matter?

Comment: That does seem to be the problem. PyCharm installed a library called ternary rather than python-ternary, when I removed it, it found the correct library and the code worked.

Comment: glad it solved the problem for you. For me however it's not working with the correct library installed

Comment: @Chrisvdberge you will need to uninstall the old library first. I added it to my answer.

Comment: @roganjosh I did uninstall the old library prior to installing the new one but that didn't work. 
Setting up a new project with new virtual environment and installing the package did do the trick though. thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice simple one. There are two libraries with "ternary" in their name. You must have done:

```
pip install ternary
```

This installs the wrong library; the library you want is from:

```
pip install python-ternary
```

You will want to run:

```
pip uninstall ternary
```

Prior to installing the correct version.

Comment: this seemed to have been the issue. I want to note though that uninstalling the package wasn't enough somehow to solve the issue. Creating a new project with a 'fresh environment' in Pycharm was necessary to get it to work.

Comment: @Chrisvdberge presumably the module was cached so your code was still looking at the wrong library. I'm not convinced that starting a new environment is _required_ for it to work, but I can't test on my end with Pycharm to find a cleaner approach

Answer (score 2):

The module you installed with `pip install ternary` is NOT https://github.com/marcharper/python-ternary but rather https://pypi.org/project/ternary/.

To install the former, [`pip install python-ternary`](https://pypi.org/project/python-ternary/).

You can see this dichotomy by [searching PyPI for "ternary"](https://pypi.org/search/?q=ternary). The entry name is what you should type in a pip command.